# How can I prevent Google from indexing documents stored on Microsoft Azure blob storage?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, noindex, azure

I have a PDF stored in Azure blob storage. When I search the name of the document on Google search engine, the full link of my PDF appears in the result. I don't want this happen.

Can I get Google stop indexing documents stored on Microsoft Azure storage?  Can I use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`?

Comment: See [Why can't I add this HTTP header to my blobs? · Issue #231 · Azure/azure-storage-net · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/231)

Comment: You can use the `rel` attribute on the link.
Example: `<a href="example.pdf" rel="nofollow">PDF</a>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a container called `$root`
2. In that container upload your `robots.txt` file blocking the folders or files you want
3. Change the file access level to Public
4. Go to `http://yourstorage.blob.core.windows.net/robots.txt` to check if everything is ok

Optional: Register your storage domain in Google Search Console to check all the statistics of indexed pages (Use the same container above to add the domain validation html file)

Comment: This does not work. Google may still have the page in the index via some other way than crawling. The content may still show up in search results. You need to set the `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` which there are no options for with a Storage Account alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can "NOINDEX" PDF files but the process is a bit different; since PDF files don't have a  section for you to insert the `meta robots` tag that you mentioned, you have to do it using the `x-robots noindex` command, which is an HTTP header command that you add to your .htaccess file.

[This article](https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-remove-pdf-files-google/) describes this process in a very clear way - if you know how to work with .htaccess files it should be simple to implement this (but be careful if you don't).

Edit: as mentioned below, depending on the server you use you won't have access to an .htaccess file but the logic is still the same: you need to do it through HTTP headers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Azure runs on IIS not Apache, so an .htaccess file isn't going to do much. You need to use web.config files to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Blob storage doesn't even give you access to IIS configuration.  Using blob storage you can set some [blob properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-properties) to change some response headers.